# Idea of the $\min$ function in proving limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Suppose you want to prove $|x - a||x + a| < \varepsilon$

You know

$$|x - a| < (2|a| + 1)$$
You need to prove

$$|x + a| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2|a| + 1}$$

So that

$$|x - a||x + a| < \varepsilon$$

Why does Michael Spivak do this:

He says you have to prove $|x + a| < \min\left(1, \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2|a| + 1}\right)$ in order to finally prove $|x + a||x - a| < \varepsilon$.

Why do we need the $\min$ function there?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418961/epsilon-delta-proof-that-lim-limits-x-to-1-frac1x-1/418991#418991

Comment: @Clarinetist that doesnt answer my specific question. Why do you need to minimize?

Comment: Because we don't know which one is smaller. Also I suggest you post the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

It will try to guess what it is about, but I may be wrong.

First, the estimation 
$$
|x-a|=|x+a-2a|\le|x+a|+2|a|<1+2|a|\tag1
$$ 
is valid only for $|x+a|<1$. That's why he needs to prove
$$
|x+a|<\frac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|}\qquad\text{and}\qquad |x+a|<1 \tag2
$$
in order to be able to combine $(1)$ and $(2)$. The condition $(2)$ can be equivalently written as
$$
|x+a|<\min\left\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|}\right\}.
$$