# Is this the right way to think of epsilon-delta proofs when $d = \min(c, e(c))$?

Tags: epsilon-delta, advice

**Introduction**.  This is a check-my-work-type of question.  The question itself only appears at the very end and if I made a mistake here, then the question becomes --- what is my thought process that's throwing me into a mess?  (Thanks.)

**My investigation**.  I've been struggling with epsilon-delta proofs --- in particular $\lim 1/x = 1$ as $x \to 1$, which has a [nice answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418961).  I have finally understood an obvious fact, which seems to be contained in the previous answer and in [related questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966789), but perhaps not too explicitly.  One important implication (to be realized) of assuming $|x - a| < \min(c, e(c))$ is that it's always true that $|x - a| < c$ and $|x - a| < e(c)$.

For example, in the $\lim 1/x = 1$ as $x \to 1$ problem, we could restrict $|x - 1| < 1/4$, say, which would imply $1/|x| < 4/3$.  Then $d = \min(1/4, 3e/4)$ implies both $1/|x| < 4/3$ and $|x - 1| < 3e/4$, so multiplying both inequalities we get

$$\left|\frac{1}{x} - 1\right| = \frac{|x - 1|}{|x|} < \frac{4}{3} \frac{3e}{4} = e,$$

as desired.  (I chose the example so as to offer a slight modification in the answers I've seen so far.)

**Conclusion**.  So my homework conclusion is --- when I see $d = \min(d_1, ..., d_k)$, I can immediately deduce $$|x - a| < d_1,\quad\cdots,\quad |x - a| < d_k.$$  That allows me to put aside the mental burden of considering what are all the cases I would have to work on if I had not yet realized this easy-but-relevant implication.

**Question**.  Although I'm saying this is obvious, I'd like to kindly ask someone to check my investigation and whether this is the right way to read (and write) epsilon-delta proofs.  (I've made a lot of obvious mistakes already.  This could be one more.)  Thank you.

Comment: You understood perfectly. Just a remark: don't write $d = \min(d_1, ..., d_k)\implies|x - a| < d_1,\dots$ but  $ |x - a| <\min(d_1, ..., d_k)\implies|x - a| < d_1,\dots$

Comment: Sure.  Thanks!  I see that.  I appreciate the feedback.  (I guess I finally understand these proofs. Happy moment for sure.)