Choosing the infimum in an Epsilon-Delta definition
I was asked to show that the limit of $z^2 = -1$ as $z$ approaches $I$ and my working out is shown below. I am stuck on a few things.
Question 1: Why do we choose $\delta$ to be the infimum? Based on my understanding, since $\epsilon$ is arbitarily small, the infimum will always be $\frac{\epsilon}{3} < 1$ and to me, choosing an infimum is pointless.
Question 2: Why do we substitute 2 different $\delta$ values in the last step. Namely we substitute $\delta = 1$ and $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Shouldn't we pick the one that is an infimum and stick to it?
Question 3: The notation for the infimum confuses me. Some textbooks show it using {} brackets as to indicate a set and others along with my lecturer use () to indicate an interval. Which is it supposed to be in the context of $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs?
Let $\epsilon$ > $0$.
By definition $|z - i| < \delta$.
Now: $|z^2+1|= (z - i)(z + i) = (z - i)(z - i + 2i)$
It is sufficient to choose $\delta = 1$; i.e., $|z - i| < 1$
By the triangle inequality:
$|z - i||z - i + 2i| < |z - i|(|z - i|+2)$
Since $|z - i| < \delta$ implies $|z^2+1|< \delta(\delta +2)$
We choose $\delta = \inf(\frac{\epsilon}{3}, 1)$.
Then: $|z-i|(|z-i|+2) < \frac{\epsilon}{3} (1+2) = \epsilon$.

Using $\inf$ there is very weird. For any set that has a minimum value the infimum coincides with the minimum. That is true, in particular for finite sets. So $\min{\frac{\epsilon}{3},1}$ would be more standard, even though of course the other notation means the same.

Not marking as a duplicate, but https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966789/why-do-we-need-min-to-choose-delta may be of interest.

@AndrewD.Hwang thank you for sharing. It makes a lot more sense now. The one thing I would like to confirm is if saying “it is sufficient to choose $\delta$ = min (a, b)” is equivalent to saying $\delta$ < a, b” since a and b are the largest possible values and choosing them to be the minimum is sufficient for our proof.

(i) The two are not equivalent: Writing "$\delta \leq a$, $b$" would mean, to me, $\delta \leq \min{a, b}$. But (ii) In this type of proof, taking $\delta $ "smaller than necessary" is all right, so in the spirit of your question, the lack of logical equivalence does not create a logical gap.

@AndrewD.Hwang So in the case of an epsilon-delta proof (using the case above as an example), shouldn't we write |−|(|−|+2)< (+2) <= $\frac{\epsilon}{3}(1+2)$ <= $\epsilon$ and NOT |−|(|−|+2)< (+2) < $\frac{\epsilon}{3}(1+2)$ < $\epsilon$

Without checking too carefully, probably yes. If it helps, there is still a strict inequality before $\delta(\delta+2)$, so the whole daisy-chain of inequalities is strict and the definition has been checked.

I assume the problem statement is supposed to be: Show that $z^2$ approaches $-1$ as $z$ approaches $i$?
The proof then roughly has the following form: Given any $\epsilon > 0$, we choose $\delta := \min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{3}\}$ and show that for any $z$ with $|z-(-1)| < \delta$ we get $|z^2-i| < \epsilon$.

With this in mind, to your questions:

In my opinion, this is mostly a matter of taste. But if you want to be completely formal (and only apply the standard $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition for convergence), choosing $\delta := \min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{3}\}$ is the right way of doing it, since you have to find a $\delta$ for any $\epsilon$.
Of course, it is not to hard to see that, in fact, it suffices to only consider "sufficiently small" $\epsilon$. Once, one understands this, one can alternatively start the proof by saying: "Given any $\epsilon > 0$ (without loss of generality $\epsilon < 1$), we choose $\delta := \frac{\epsilon}{3}$..."

Since $\delta$ is defined as the minimum of both values, you can use both estimates $\delta < 1$ and $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ wherever you want. And using each one once here, happens to give the nice upper bound $< \epsilon$.

The notation $\inf(\frac{\epsilon}{3},1)$ seems very weird to me. I would always use $\inf\{\frac{\epsilon}{3},1\}$ (or, even better, $\min\{\frac{\epsilon}{3},1\}$) here. If $(\frac{\epsilon}{3},1)$ refers to the interval between $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ and $1$ in the first notation (which is the standard interpretation), this isn't even correct in the case that $\frac{\epsilon}{3}>1$ (and certainly confusing in any case).



Thank you for your reply. That clears up a lot. One thing though regarding $\epsilon$ < 1 for instance. Are we able to say this since we know the largest possible value it can take on is 1? Also, if we chose $\delta$ < $\frac {\epsilon}{3}$ doesn’t that mean $\delta$ is not <1?

Do you mean, why we can assume $\epsilon < 1$ without loss of generality?
Intuitively, this is because $f(x)$ converging to $f(y)$ for $x$ converging to $y$ just means: $f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $f(y)$ if $x$ gets close to $y$. Hence, we are only interested in $x$ which are close to $y$. Though, one has to first formally prove such a lemma, before one may use it (proving such a statement is a nice exercise in applying the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition in a more abstract setting. But maybe a bit much to start with). When in doubt, you can always just work with general $\epsilon$

Sorry, I meant in regards to your point 2. By choosing $\delta$ = min{$\frac{\epsilon}{3}$, 1}, are we not choosing one or the other and not both?

Also, by setting the minimum value, does that mean the largest value our delta can take is 1, and so $\delta$ < 1?

We are choosing the minimum. Whether this means $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ or $\delta = 1$ depends on the value of $\epsilon$. The point is: It doesn't matter for the rest of the proof which of the cases holds. We only use $\delta \leq \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ and $\delta \leq 1$ which is true in any case.

Alternatively, you could also do a case distinction, i.e. split your proof in two cases: "If $\epsilon \geq 3$ we choose $\delta = 1$ and .... Otherwise, we choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ and ...." Then, in each of the two cases, you know exactly what $\delta$ is (and can use this). This would yield an equally valid proof, just a bit longer.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
