# Validity of an epsilon delta proof.

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I’ve watched a video on how to prove that $$\lim_{x\to3}x^2=9$$
Using the epsilon-delta definition of a limit, but i have a slightly different proof and I’m wondering whether it is true or false.

**The Proof:**

Given $\epsilon >0$, let $\delta=\epsilon/6$, suppose $|x-3|<\delta$, then:
$$|x-3|< \frac{\epsilon}{6} \iff 6 |x-3| <\epsilon$$
Since $x$ is very close to $3$ it follows that $|x+3|<6$, which implies that:
$$|x-3| |x+3| <|x-3|6<\epsilon$$
$$|x^2-9|<\epsilon$$
If you think that my argument in $|x+3|<6$ is not rigorous enough you can check it that like this:
$$\delta<x-3<\delta \iff 6-\delta<|x+3|<6+\delta$$
We can make the absolute calues because $6-\delta>0$

Comment: "because $6-\delta>0$" Not necessarily. What if $\epsilon=37$?

Comment: "Since $x$ is very close to $3$ it follows that $|x+3|<6$," what about $x = 3.00001?$

Comment: Personally, I start with $|x - 3| < \delta \implies -\delta < (x-3) < \delta \implies (3-\delta) < x < (3+\delta).$  Then, I will typically add an artificial constraint (e.g. $\delta \leq [1/2]$), and then derive a separate constraint on $\epsilon$ (e.g. $\delta < [\epsilon/7]$) or something like that.  Then, I will put it all together via $\delta \leq \min([1/2], [\epsilon/10])$, or something that looks like that.  This will be my **candidate specification**.  Then, I will manually verify that my candidate specification works against the definition of a limit converging to a value.

Comment: The artificial constraint $(e.g. \delta \leq [1/2]$) is nothing more than a contrivance that allows me to assume that $\delta^2 < \delta.$  This facilitates my specifying a **linear** relationship between $\delta$ and $\epsilon.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0$, we want $\delta>0$ such that

$$|x-3|<\delta\implies |x+3||x-3|<\epsilon$$

$x $ is close to $ 3 $, so we can add the condition $$|x-3|<\color{red}{1}$$
which is equivalent to
$$2<x<4 $$
this gives
$$5<x+3<7$$

So,
$$|x-3|<1\implies$$
$$ |x-3||x+3|<7|x-3|$$
thus we Just need to find $ \delta $ satisfying

$$|x-3|<\color{red}{1}\wedge |x-3|<\delta\implies$$
$$ |x-3|<\frac{\epsilon}{7}$$

From here, we see that we can take
$$\delta=\min(\color{red}{1},\frac{\epsilon}{7})$$

Comment: Unclear how far you wish to pursue rigor.  See for example, the Addendum to my answer of [this query](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4082296/proving-lim-x-to-0-frac1x-does-not-exist-by-contradiction-the-case), where manual verification is discussed.

Comment: Why did you put $\delta = min(1,\epsilon\7)$, it should be $\delta=\epsilon/7$?  @hamam_Abdallah

Comment: @Yassir You must add the condition $|x-3|<1$ So $\delta $ should be smaller than $1$