# Definition of the Limit: Question about $|f(x)-L|$ manipulation to find a suitable delta

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

In the definition of the limit, often the first step to find a suitable delta is to manipulate $|f(x)-L|$ to look something like $|x-a|$, after that we can see delta in terms of epsilon that we can choose as a guess.

I would like to ask why is it that we can use this manipulation as delta and end up satisfying the statement:

$|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$

All the videos I have watched, after extracting $|x-a|$ from $|f(x)-L|$ goes like 'look! we have found an appropriate delta, now we have to check if this works'. I am having trouble understanding how this indeed satisfies the condition, or how the extraction provides us with a good guess for delta.

Say for example, given $\lim_{x\to 1}(2x+3)=5$

We write $|2x+3-5|$, and then manipulate that to be:
$|2x-2|$, $2|x-1|$. We found $|x-a|$ (in this case, $|x-1|$), so we say that the suitable $\delta$ is $\epsilon/2$, because we manipulated $|2x-2|<\epsilon$ to be $|x-1|<\epsilon/2$

How does this manipulation give us a good guess for delta?

Comment: Because if you have $|f(x)-L|<\text{ something in terms of $|x-a|$}$ and you make $|x-a|$ sufficiently small (choose a good $\delta$...) you make $|f(x)-L|$ small

Comment: Unless you show us a concrete example of a specific proof, how can we explain to you how it works? There is not a universal method for doing these proofs except to somehow (by whatever means) find a $\delta$, usually depending on $\varepsilon$ in some way, that enables $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ to be deduced from $0<|x-a|<\delta$. Telling us you have seen a lot of explanations that you didn't understand is not sufficient information to respond to. Show us exactly where your doubt occurred.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3659232/72031 as well as discussion in comments thereof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example $$\lim_{x\to 1}(2x+3)=5$$
you have $f(x) = 2x+3$ and $L=5,$ so as you showed, you write
$$\lvert f(x)-L \rvert = \lvert (2x+3)-5 \rvert = \lvert 2x - 2\rvert. $$

You also have $a = 1,$ so $\lvert x - a \rvert = \lvert x - 1 \rvert.$
So if you notice that $\lvert 2x - 2\rvert = 2\lvert x - 1\rvert,$ you will have discovered that
$$\lvert f(x)-L \rvert = 2\lvert x - a \rvert. $$

Since the left and right sides of this equation are equal quantities, we know that
$\lvert f(x)-L \rvert < \epsilon$ if and only if $2\lvert x - a \rvert < \epsilon,$
while $2\lvert x - a \rvert < \epsilon$ is true if and only if
$\lvert x - a \rvert < \frac\epsilon2$.

Since each of these inequalities is true **if and only if** the others are true,
we can work backwards from the end:

If $\lvert x - a \rvert < \frac\epsilon2$ then $2\lvert x - a \rvert < \epsilon.$

If $2\lvert x - a \rvert < \epsilon$ then $\lvert f(x)-L \rvert < \epsilon.$

Therefore, if $\lvert x - a \rvert < \frac\epsilon2$ then
$\lvert f(x)-L \rvert < \epsilon.$

That is the implication in the definition of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L,$ except that we have $\frac\epsilon2$ where the definition has $\delta.$

So for any $\epsilon > 0,$ we know that there is a number that we can call $\delta$
and that happens to be equal to $\frac\epsilon2$ such that
$\lvert f(x)-L \rvert < \epsilon$ whenever $\lvert x - a \rvert < \delta.$
And that is exactly the definition of the limit.

---

I think it is important to remember that the step of "finding $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$" is a technique to help you prepare to write a delta-epsilon proof;
it is not part of the proof itself.
Indeed, if you were very lucky and guessed (without doing any calculations at all)
that you could set $\delta$ equal to $\frac\epsilon2$ in your proof,
you would find when you wrote the proof that this actually worked as desired.
But most of us are not such lucky guessers, so we need a little calculation to help us with the guesses.

But there is no general method (at least none I am aware of) to tell you how to manipulate any arbitrary differentiable function $f(x)$ in order to find the derivative of $f(x)$ at any particular value of $x.$
You might be able to generalize the method above to work for any linear function,
but you will need a different method for a quadratic function,
another for an exponential function, etc.

So even with these techniques, the answer to "how did you know" is generally that you did **not** know how to do it when you started, but you used intuition, experience,
and sometimes trial and error (the manipulation looked like it would get you a suitable way to express $\delta$, but it did not) until you found a proof that worked.

Answer (score 0):

$|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$ satisface because the process you construct your $\delta$.
The process of manipulate $|f(x)-L|$ is precisely to garante that when you do the inverse process, the obtained $\epsilon$ is small enough 
**Eg** suppouse we wanna show that 
$f(x)=x²+7x+6$ is continues at $x=1$
First, note that we need that
$|x²+7x+6-14|<\epsilon$
but this is
$|x²+7x-8|<\epsilon$
On the other hand, $x²+7x-8$ can be factorized as $(x+8)(x-1)$. 
We want to show that, no matter how small is the distance ($\delta$) between a point $x$ and $1$  to form an open interval in the domain, it always exist an open interval in range that contains $f(1)$ so, start by assuming a distance $\delta=1$ so
$|x-1|<1$ so if this happens, I need to know what happens with $|x+8|$? Note that
$|x+8|=|x-1+1+8|<|x-1|+9<1+9=10$ this last, by our first assumption, so this means that it will be helpful using $\delta= \frac{\epsilon}{10}$
So we can start by saying, 
let be $\delta=min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{10})$ and so on...
this election of $\delta$, guarantees that 
$|x+8||x-1|$ will be always minor than $\epsilon$
I hope this can help you bro.