What does this step in the epsilon delta proof for limit of following function mean?
I came across the following problem as i was reading an proof for limit of $f(x, y) =\large \frac{4xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$ using epsilon delta definition of the limit.
The book is Thomas Calculus 14th edition, chapter 14.
Below is the line of proof i could not understand
$\Large\frac{4|x|y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ $\le 4|x| = 4\sqrt{x^2}\le 4\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
After which they say if we let $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{4}$
They lost me in the inequalities, help me understand in simple words and also tell me what is the entire point of this epsilon delta jargon.

Is it that you do not understand how the inequality is derived?

@cansomeonehelpmeout has provided an answer for why the inequality is true. Explaining "the entire point of all this epsilon delta jargon" is a much harder question to answer. The accepted answer here might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3658590/understanding-epsilon-delta-proof?rq=1

$x^2 \ge 0$ so $y^2 \le x^2+y^2$ so $\frac {y^2}{x^2 + y^2} \le 1$.  Are you with me so far?  So $\frac {4|x|y^2}{x^2+y^2} = 4|x|\cdot \frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}=4|x|\cdot 1 = 4|x|$.  Meanwhile $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$ while $y^2\ge 0$ so $x^2 + y^2 \ge x^2$ and $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ge \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.  So $4|x|=4\sqrt{x^2} \le 4\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

This all relies on $K^2 \ge 0$ so:

$K^2 + M^2 \ge M^2$
$\sqrt{K^2+M^2} \ge \sqrt{M^2}$
$\frac {M^2}{K^2 + M^2} \le 1$

The text is assuming the reader is fully comfortable with the conclusions and sees them immediately without question.
To add in extra steps:
$\frac {4|x|y^2}{x^2 + y^2} = $
$4|x|\cdot\frac {y^2}{x^2 + y^2} =$
$4|x|\cdot\frac {0 + y^2}{x^2 + y^2}\le$
$4|x|\cdot\frac {x^2 + y^2}{x^2 + y^2} =$
$4|x|\cdot 1=$
$4|x| = $
$4\sqrt{x^2} = $
$4\sqrt{x^2 + 0} \le $
$4\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$
I really hope this now makes everything very clear.

If $y=0$ then $0\leq 1$ is true. If $y\neq 0$, then $$\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2+1}\leq 1$$

Correct, but it's better to prove this without dividing by $y$, which might be $0$.
