# proof (1/bn) -> (1/b) from abbott Understanding Analysis.

Tags: analysis

[image]
[image]
Anyone can explain this better than the book?  It's difficult to understand for me.

What is the worst-case? 
Why does the bound on the size of $|\frac{1}{b_n}-\frac{1}{b}|$ matter?

Comment: Can you say what the original statement, (iv) was?

Comment: (iii) lim(anbn) = ab
(iv) lim(an/bn) = a/b provied b is not 0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that $(b_n) \to b$ implies $\left(\frac{1}{b_n}\right) \to \frac{1}{b}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54754/proving-that-b-n-to-b-implies-left-frac1b-n-right-to-frac1b)

Answer (score 1):

Remember the definition of the limit- we want to make $|\frac{1}{b_n}-\frac{1}{b}|=\frac{|b|-|b_n|}{|b_n||b|}$ arbitrarily small, meaning for any $\epsilon>0$, there is some $N$ such that for all $n$ such that if $n\geq N$, then $\frac{|b|-|b_n|}{|b_n||b|}<\epsilon$. We know that we can make $|b|-|b_n|$ arbitrarily small, because $b_n\to b$. However, we still have to worry about $\frac{1}{|b_n||b|}$ because if it gets too big, we can't say that the whole fraction gets arbitrarily small. The proof shows that we can find an index $N_1$ to make $|b_n-b|$ small enough for our purposes, and an index $N_2$ to make $|b_n|$ big enough for our purposes. For all $n\geq\max{N_1,N_2}$, we have both sufficiently small $|b_n-b|$ and sufficiently large $|b_n|$ that we can bound $|\frac{1}{b_n}-\frac{1}{b}|$ by $\epsilon$, the details of which are all there.

That gives us that the limit of $\frac{1}{b_n}$ is $\frac{1}{b}$. Then, for any sequences $a_n\to a, b_n\to b$ with $b\neq 0$, we get that $\frac{a_n}{b_n}=a_n\frac{1}{b_n}=a\frac{1}{b}$ by (iii).

Comment: Thank you so much !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: could you help me another one?

Comment: could you help me http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976615/order-limit-theorem-from-understanding-analysis-by-abbott 

this one also..?  if you can