# Order limit theorem from understanding analysis by Abbott

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> **Theorem** $\mathbf{2.3.4}$ **(Order Limit Theorem).** *Assume* $\lim a_n=a$ *and* $\lim b_n=b$.
>
> 1. *If* $a_n\ge 0$ *for all* $n\in\Bbb N$, *then* $a\ge 0$.
> 2. *If* $a_n\le b_n$ *for all* $n\in\Bbb N$, *then* $a\le b$.
> 3. *If there exists* $c\in\mathbf{R}$ *for which* $c\le b_n$ *for all $n\in\Bbb N$, *then* $c\le b$. *Similarly, if* $a_n\le c$ *for all* $n\in\Bbb N$, *then* $a\le c$.

(The entire image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo9W1.png).)

Where did the hypothesis that $a_n\ge 0$ come from?

Is this because $n>0$?

Comment: A question asking for an explanation of textual material is clearly not off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

No, it just tells if $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n \in N$, then the result is so and so. This is the first hypothesis.
For example, consider this sentence - 'If it will rain today, I will not go to play.' - Here, I can't question  Why  it will rain ?

Comment: thank you so much I got it. since n is all the natural numbers. Also N italic is natural number. Due to the fact that, a N >= 0. Thank you so much !

Comment: No, you are finding reason why $a_n \ge 0$, but I am saying there is no reason for it.