# Basic Analysis: A sequence $b_n$ converges to nonzero $b$, prove that $\frac{1}{b_n}$ converges to $\frac{1}{b}$

Tags: real-analysis

I've been struggling on this proof and I'd greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

**If a sequence $(b_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is never zero and converges to a non-zero term $b$, show that $\frac{1}{b_{n}}$ converges to $\frac{1}{b}$**

I'm pretty sure I need to use triangle inequality and the definition of convergence, but beyond that I just can't put the pieces together. Thanks for reading

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that $(b_n) \to b$ implies $\left(\frac{1}{b_n}\right) \to \frac{1}{b}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54754/proving-that-b-n-to-b-implies-left-frac1b-n-right-to-frac1b)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Hint** : Estimate $|\frac{1}{b_n}-\frac{1}{b}|$ by 
$$
|\frac{1}{b_n}-\frac{1}{b}|=\frac{|b-b_n|}{|b.b_n|}
$$
and "control" the denominator.